# Как сделать, чтобы сервис с медиаплеер останавливался, когда приложение свернуто или экран выключен?

Tags: android, service, mediaplayer

Я новичок в Android studio.Я хочу сделать, чтобы сервис с медиаплеером прерывался, когда приложение свернуто или экран выключен.

`public class PlayService extends Service {

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysound);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mPlayer.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.stop();
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесите следующие изменения ваш сервис:

```
public class PlayService extends Service {
      private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
      String PLAY_ACTION = "com.app.action.play";
      String STOP_ACTION = "com.app.action.stop";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysound);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(PLAY_ACTION)) {
       mPlayer.start();
     } else if(intent.getAction().equals(STOP_ACTION)) {
                if(nPlayer != null){
                    mPlayer.stop();
                  }                  
     }



    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.stop();
}`
```

Добавьте эти строки в активити откуда вы запускаете сервис радио:

```
    String PLAY_ACTION = "com.app.action.play";
    String STOP_ACTION = "com.app.action.stop";
```

Запуск сервиса:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PLAY_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
```

В этом же активити добавте метод `onPause()` если его нет, он будет иметь следующий вид:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PLAY_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но тогда вылезает другая проблема, при смене активити медиаплеер тоже останавливается.

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз) В итоге решил эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Итоговый код, который получился у меня, для тех, кто будет искать ответ на что-то подобное в будущем:

```
public class PlayService extends Service {
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
String PLAY_ACTION = "com.app.action.play";
String STOP_ACTION = "com.app.action.stop";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysound);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PLAY_ACTION)) {
        mPlayer.start();
    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(STOP_ACTION)) {
        if(mPlayer != null){
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }



    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.stop();
}}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

String PLAY_ACTION = "com.app.action.play";
String STOP_ACTION = "com.app.action.stop";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PLAY_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(STOP_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PLAY_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    super.onResume();
}
///Для того, чтобы музыка продолжала играть в других активити при переходах, скопируйте `@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(STOP_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, PlayService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PLAY_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    super.onResume();`
//В другие активити
```